# How do I keep my CTA image with 100% width from stretching when adjusting the height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am making a website and I need a CTA image. 
I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have made a custom CSS to adjust how the image will look. I've put it so that it takes up the whole width of the screen, so `width: 100%;`
When I adjust the size of the screen, the image is responsive and also adjusts itself so that it will turn smaller and fit the whole screen. But when is on a regular big sized screen the image takes up the whole website so **I want to be able to leave it as 100% width but with a smaller height.** When I try adjusting the max-height it just ends up stretching the image and it is not appealing to look at. What should I do?

This is the HTML Section:

```
<!-- CTA Section -->
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="I/CTA.png">
        <div class="img-overlay">
            Want to see what more we have to offer? 
            <br><br>
            <a href="coffee.html"><button class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
             Click here</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /.img-wrapper -->
```

This is the CSS section of the code:

```
.img-wrapper {
position: relative;
 }

 .img-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 650px;
 }

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.img-overlay:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 60%;
}

button {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.btn-responsive {
  /* matches 'btn-md' */
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width:760px) { 
    /* matches 'btn-xs' */
    .btn-responsive {
        padding: 1px 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit?v=control), though it hasn't so good [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) yet, so a solution making use of `background-image` might be needed (based on the browser support you require)

Here is a solution using `object-fit`

```
 .img-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
 }
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y3Lbf16m/)

Stack snippet

```css
.img-wrapper {
position: relative;
 }

 .img-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
 }

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.img-overlay:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 60%;
}

button {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.btn-responsive {
  /* matches 'btn-md' */
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width:760px) { 
    /* matches 'btn-xs' */
    .btn-responsive {
        padding: 1px 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- CTA Section -->
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/350/nature/1/">
        <div class="img-overlay">
            Want to see what more we have to offer? 
            <br><br>
            <a href="coffee.html"><button class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
             Click here</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

Here is another using `background-image`.

The trick for making this work, is to keep the image in place, but with `visiblity: hidden` set. This will make the image wrapper size proper, and then the background image adjust without stretching.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y3Lbf16m/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.img-overlay:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 60%;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.btn-responsive {
  /* matches 'btn-md' */
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width:760px) {
  /* matches 'btn-xs' */
  .btn-responsive {
    padding: 1px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- CTA Section -->
<div class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/350/nature/1/)">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/350/nature/1/">
  <div class="img-overlay">
    Want to see what more we have to offer?
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="coffee.html">
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        Click here</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```